# How To See SQL Code in phpmyadmin SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to see the manual SQL code for a table I created using the graphical user interface. Is there a way to do this and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename
```

see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html)

Answer (score 2):

nbk is correct that you would use the SHOW CREATE TABLE command, which is also implemented graphically in phpMyAdmin. From the database structure page (where you see a list of tables), click to select the checkbox for any tables you wish to see the syntax for and the use the "With selected:" dropdown menu on the page to pick "Show create".

It does the same thing, but using the phpMyAdmin interface.

### "With selected:" dropdown on the table page

[image: "With selected:" dropdown]

### Output of "Show create"

[image: "Show create" output]

Comment: Thanks @nbk, good suggestion! I hope this covers it well enough now.